# Can I use ECHO to execute commands?

Tags: linux, shell, printing, scripting, echo

I've come up with a cool script that will produce the output that I need, but it only displays on the screen, so I have to copy, then paste in the commands to get them to execute. Here's the abbreviated version of my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
runc=/etc/csf/csf.pl -d
for IP in `tail -400 iptext.txt`
do
cc=`geoiplookup $IP`
echo -e $runc $IP    $cc | grep Algeria
echo -e $runc $IP    $cc | grep Argentina
echo -e $runc $IP    $cc | grep Armenia
echo -e $runc $IP    $cc | grep Azerbaijan
echo -e $runc $IP    $cc | grep Bolivia
echo -e $runc $IP    $cc | grep Brazil
done
```

Okay, so it loops through the list of IP addresses in iptext.txt, then does a geoIP lookup on each, if (in this example) there are two geoIP matches in the list, let's say for Armenia and Brazil, I will see output like this to the shell window:

```
/etc/csf/csf.pl -d 46.162.242.17 GeoIP Country Edition: AM, Armenia
/etc/csf/csf.pl -d 200.147.38.50 GeoIP Country Edition: BR, Brazil
```

This is great, but I want more than just output, I actually want the `/etc/csf/csf.pl -d` command to run, and block (just and only) the IP in the lines that match the country name, in the list.

I've tried various things with my limited knowledge of shell scripting, but so far, nothing seems to work. So is there some option for ECHO I am missing that would actually run the command rather than just printing out the line?

Comment: I have rollback your inclusion of an answer in the question itself. Please post your own answer or approve one of the existing one. Note that your solution was almost identical to Flo Doe's answer.

Answer (score 50):

Just put your command into parenthesis like this:

```
echo $(ls)
```

You can also have text before the command

```
echo "The date is $(date)"
```

For Example

```
echo "Enter Text Here $(Command Here)"
```

Answer (score 27):

A simple way that won't need modification of your script would be to pipe the command's output to another bash instance. Like this:

```
yourscript | bash -
```

The `-` tells bash that it should read commands from stdin.

---

However, if you are not searching for a quick solution, it is possible to build and execute the command dynamically as well. Like this:

```
cmd="ls"
if [ "foo" != "bar" ] ; then
    cmd="$cmd -a"
then

# ... and so on

# now execute it:
$cmd
```

Comment: You could also pipe the `for` loop into `bash`: `for x in ...; do ...; done | bash -`

Comment: @glennjackman I wasn't sure and too lazy to test ;) ... piping the output of the loop sounds like the best solution to me. thx

Answer (score 15):

You can use `eval` to execute a string:

```
eval $cmdstring
```

Answer (score 10):

There is a bash builtin eval, this executes commands like they were typed in at your shell. For example within your script you can do the following:

```
eval $(echo -e $runc $IP    $cc | grep Algeria)
```

This will process your echo in a subshell and the output will be executed like you typed it in your shell followed by enter.

See below exerpt from bash manual:

> eval [arg ...]
>                 The  args are read and concatenated together into a single command.  This command is then read and executed by the shell, and its exit status is returned as
>                 the value of eval.  If there are no args, or only null arguments, eval returns 0.

Answer (score 7):

```
echo `pwd`
```

above command works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep -E` and a pattern instead:

```
$runc $IP    $cc | grep -E 'Algeria|Argentina|...'
```

Explanation: `echo` will print the command but not execute it. Just omit it to actually execute the command.

And instead of running the script 5 times, use `grep` to search for any of the five patterns at once.

And you should use

```
cc=$(geoiplookup $IP)
```

instead of backticks; it's safer.

Answer (score 0):

You should pipe those `echo` and `grep` commands further like this:

```bash
...
echo -e "$runc $IP    $cc" | grep Algeria | sh
...
```

---

Lets take this command as an example:

```bash
$ echo -e "echo AAA\necho BBB\necho CCC"

echo AAA
echo BBB
echo CCC
```

From that I only need `AAA`:

```bash
$ echo -e "echo AAA\necho BBB\necho CCC" | grep AAA

echo AAA
```

Now to actually execute that `echo AAA`:

- `sh` or `bash`

```bash
$ echo -e "echo AAA\necho BBB\necho CCC" | grep AAA | sh

AAA
```

- `xargs`

```bash
$ echo -e "echo AAA\necho BBB\necho CCC" | grep AAA | xargs command

AAA
```

---

You can use `tee` if you actually need to **both** print and execute the command:

```bash
$ echo -e "echo AAA\necho BBB\necho CCC" | grep AAA | tee /dev/tty | sh

echo AAA
AAA
```

or

```bash
$ echo -e "echo AAA\necho BBB\necho CCC" | grep AAA | tee >(sh)

echo AAA
echo
```

`xargs -t` kinda works similarly:

```bash
$ echo -e "echo AAA\necho BBB\necho CCC" | grep AAA | xargs -t command

command echo AAA
AAA
```

---

`xargs` and `sh`/`bash` might not always work as expected, for example:

```bash
$ echo "echo echo | rev" | tee /dev/tty | xargs command

echo echo | rev
echo | rev
```

vs:

```bash
$ echo "echo echo | rev" | tee /dev/tty | sh

echo echo | rev
ohce
```

---

Using `tee` with multiple redirections:

```bash
$ echo "echo echo | rev" | tee >(sh) >(xargs command)

echo echo | rev
ohce
echo | rev
```